# @RestResource( exported=false ) ignored

Tags: json, spring, spring-data-rest

as in title - my @RestResource(exported=false) is ignored on field. Spring data rest still want to make json from it, I would like to simply skip it for now, as changing rel in WorkflowEvent gave me nothing..

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "submission")
@OrderBy("date desc")
@RestResource(exported = false)
private List<WorkflowEvent> events = new ArrayList<WorkflowEvent>();
```

I get:

```
{"timestamp":1410850806347,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException","message":"Could not write JSON: Detected multiple association links with same relation type! Disambiguate association @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(insertable=true, unique=false, referencedColumnName=, columnDefinition=, name=submission_id, updatable=true, nullable=true, table=, foreignKey=@javax.persistence.ForeignKey(name=, value=CONSTRAINT, foreignKeyDefinition=)) @javax.persistence.ManyToOne(fetch=EAGER, cascade=[], optional=true, targetEntity=void) @org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource(description=@org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.Description(value=), path=, exported=false, rel=) private mypackage.MyClass mypackage.WorkflowEvent.myclass using @RestResource!; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Detected multiple association links with same relation*
```

ofcourse it works when I comment this field.

My versions:

```
\- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-core:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.16.0.RELEASE:compile
```

Answer (score 11):

`@RestResources` is only supported on domain properties that point to managed resources. Thus, if you don't expose `WorkflowEvent` by a Spring Data REST managed repository, the annotation has no effect whatsoever. In this case, simply use an `@JsonIgnore` to let Jackson not render the property.

Comment: Even when it has repository then @RestResource(exported=false) on WorkflowEvent property in some other entity has no effect. If I remove repository it still tries to create link to WorkflowEvent entity.. It crashes with  "Detected multiple association links" on mypackage.WorkflowEvent.submission

Comment: This seems to be getting quite involved. Any chance you provide a sample project to look at?

Comment: seems that not having repository for any of properties cause this (I have removed one for WorkflowEvent now to reproduce it). If its there - everything is ok - links are generated and working fine. Oliver - if there is no rational reason for that I will try to create some small project with this issue.

Comment: While `@JsonIgnore` works, I feel that Spring Data REST should have a way to support not rendering properties **only** on the frontend REST side. It should not rely on a Jackson annotation, which may conflict with other backend logic should the backend also use Jackson for json serialization (e.g. to take snapshots of entities)

Comment: @JWLim — That's what [projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts) are for.

Comment: But you can't have a default projection on a single resource as far as I can see so Jackson annotations are required.

Comment: This should be documented in the SD Rest documentation if it is not already. Just ran into this issue, reviewed the docs a few times and found no mention of this.